# Cox model with ridge term: how to choose value of theta?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, rms

The coxph() function in R package "survival" is used to fit the Cox proportional hazards model. This function allows a ridge() term in the formula to penalise selected terms, which requires the user to specify theta. What is the recommended way to chose the value of theta? Perhaps cross-validation?

Comment: How many events are there?  You need a lot of events to be able to use the data to select the amount of shrinkage.

Comment: @Frank Harrell, 48 events, with total sample size a few thousand. I was thinking to use your advice in your rms book regarding effect estimation, that is, to shrink all predictors except the predictor of interest to avoid over-fitting.

Comment: Shinkage is needed but selection of the shrinkage parameter would have to be defined from subject matter considerations as you'll find a lot of noise in cross-validation optimization of shrinkage parameters.  Better would be to use data reduction (unsupervised learning) to limit how many variables get regression coefficients.  Richard Riley et al have sample size calculation algorithms but roughly you may be able to have only 3 degrees of freedom fitted against the outcome.  Your effective sample size is 48.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider data reduction. I guess you might be referring to your redun() function in Hmisc?

Comment: More so principal components analysis, sparse PCA, variable clustering.  There is a chapter on data reduction in [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc).  There is also a new case study at the end of RMS.  I really like sparse PCA.

Comment: Do you have any guidance / examples of how one would use subject matter knowledge to select theta value?

Comment: That is discussed in the Bayesian modeling literature.  The penalties relate directly to the width of prior distributions on parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148667/discussion-between-user167591-and-frank-harrell).